# caching a result in an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

the code :

```
function CallSyncAjax(url, resid) {
try { parent.TimeOut(); } catch (ex) { }
var xmlhttp = new GetXmlHttp();
if (xmlhttp) {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp && xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {//we got something back..
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var StrResponse;
                StrResponse = xmlhttp.responseText.split('@@@');
                if (xmlhttp.responseText != "") {
                    if (StrResponse[0] != "") {

                        if (resid == "1000") {
                            //this function exist in ContactsList.apsx
                            AddGroupToMenu(StrResponse[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("post", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

i am calling this function from a page on a button click like this :

```
CallSyncAjax("?ExtFlag=saveGroup&AjaxFalg=SpecialRequest&groupName=" + TxtGroupName.GetText() + "&groupDesc=" + TxtgroupDesc.GetText(), "1000");
```

my question is can i cache the result so when i click again to the button the ajax call wont be called and just read the result from the cache ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of objects

```
{
    url:  "",
    result: ""
}
```

(basically a key/value dictionary) and every time CallSyncAjax function is called, check if URL already been called and if so - retrieve respective result from the array. Otherwise make an AJAX call and store new url/result pair in the array.